# execute c# code at runtime from code file

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, csharpcodeprovider

I have a **WPF C#** application that contains a button.

The code of the button click is written in separate text file which will be placed in the applications runtime directory.

I want to ***execute*** that code placed in the text file on the click of the button.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=CSharpCodeProvider&x=0&y=0&sbo=kw

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to compile code on-the-fly. In particular, see [CompileAssemblyFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromfile.aspx).

Answer (score 99):

Code sample for executing compiled on fly class method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string source =
            @"
namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");
        }
    }
}
            ";

             Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
                };
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

            CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
                {GenerateInMemory = true,
                 GenerateExecutable = false};

            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);

            if (results.Errors.Count != 0)
                throw new Exception("Mission failed!");

            object o = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Foo.Bar");
            MethodInfo mi = o.GetType().GetMethod("SayHello");
            mi.Invoke(o, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added in memory compilation

Comment: Post sample of your code, please. My code doesn't rise file not found exception.

Comment: I am executing the same code in a new console without any change.

Comment: It's work fine for me. May you give me call stack where the exception was thrown?

Comment: It works for me in .NET 4.0 Client Profile (for both "v3.5" and "v4.0") -- I'm wondering, how would I do it with a DataContext? (i.e. the code I want to pass in is "Property >= 5 && Property < 10" and the method I would wrap it in is essentially "public object GetValue() { return " + code + " }" -- where "Property" is a property on a given datacontext...

Comment: @VinodMaurya I have noticed I get File not found if compiling fails. Do check for results.Errors.Count before trying to Invoke.

Answer (score 23):

I recommend having a look at [Microsoft Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx), and specifically its `ScriptEngine` class.
Here are a few good examples to start with:

1. [Introduction to the Roslyn Scripting API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx)
2. [Using Roslyn ScriptEngine for a ValueConverter to process user input](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/338088/Using-Roslyn-ScriptEngine-for-a-ValueConverter-to).

Usage example:

```
var session = Session.Create();
var engine = new ScriptEngine();
engine.Execute("using System;", session);
engine.Execute("double Sin(double d) { return Math.Sin(d); }", session);
engine.Execute("MessageBox.Show(Sin(1.0));", session);
```

Comment: Before you search for the download, just use the Package-Manager: `Install-Package Roslyn`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like someone created a library for this called [C# Eval](https://web.archive.org/web/20170718133154/http://csharp-eval.com/).

EDIT: Updated link to point to Archive.org as it seems like the [original site](http://csharp-eval.com/) is dead.

Comment: @RichO'Kelly, thanks - I updated it to point to the archive.org version.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a  [CSharpCodeProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

There are several samples to understand how does it work.

1  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12499/Run-Time-Code-Generation-I-Compile-C-Code-using-Mi

The important point of this example that you can do all things on flay in fact.

```
myCompilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
myCompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
```

2  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10324/Compiling-code-during-runtime

This example is good coz you can create dll file and so it can be shared between other applications.

Basically you can search for http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=csharpcodeprovider&x=0&y=0&sbo=kw&pgnum=6  and get more useful links.