# Best approach for allowing users to define rules in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rules

I've been looking into rules engines and such, but I really am not sure where to start. This is more for experimentation, but I'd like to implement something like this for work in the future. Basically, I have an application where a user submits a form and populates a POCO object with several properties. I want the administrator of the application to be able to define rules based on the properties of said object and store them in a relational database. When the form is submitted, I would then make a decision based on the user defined rules. For example, the admin can go into the application and define rules like following:

```
if (typeID == 4 && request.benchMarkScore < 10) {
    request.denied = true;
    request.denyReasons.Add("Score too low for this product");
}
```

Here's my POCO Object example:

```
class Request
{
    public int benchMarkScore { get; set; }
    public int typeID { get; set; }
    public double rate { get; set; }
    public bool isEligable { get; set; }
    public bool denied { get; set; }
    public List<string> denyReasons { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> adjustments;
}
```

Granted I know this is an overly simplified example, but I come across many situations where I users could benefit from this functionality in my applications. I'm not looking for a complete solution, but instead an idea of where to start.

Comment: Rules engines are somewhat different from what you're describing; they define *business rules*.    What I think you're really looking for are *validation libraries.*  As in user input validation.  Something like this: http://tnvalidate.codeplex.com/site/search?query=fluent%20validation&ac=4

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways you could go about this.  One suggestion would be to leverage reflection itself, and allow admins to apply a rule.  I'm going to keep this simple, but a rule would consist of:

1. A bunch of properties, operands, and values
2. The reason(s) for denial.

So let's define that.  I am going to keep this simple and just handle equality, you can define additional ones:

```
public enum Operand
{
    Equals
}
```

Now, we can define an interface called `IRule`.  I am defining an interface so that in the future, you could potentially put special, more complicated, rules in.

```
public interface IRule<TPOCO> where TPOCO : class
{
    bool IsValid(TPOCO poco);
}
```

And now we'll define our Rule class (Note: this doesn't handle *indexed* properties):

```
public class PropertyCompareRule : IRule<Request>
{
    private sealed class PropertyCompare
    {
        public string PropertyName {get; set; }
        public Operand Operand {get; set; }
        public object Value {get; set;}
        public string Reason {get; set; }
    }
    private List<PropertyCompare> _comparers = new List<PropertyCompare>();

    public bool IsValid(Request poco)
    {
        bool isValid = true; // let's be optimistic!
        PropertyInfo[] properties = poco.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where((property) => property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && property.CanRead).ToArray();
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            foreach(var comparer in _comparers)
            {
                bool localIsValid;
                if(comparer.PropertyName == property.Name)
                {
                    object val = property.GetValue(poco, null);
                    switch(comparer.Operand)
                    {
                        case Operand.Equals:
                            {
                                localIsValid = object.Equals(val, property.Value);
                                break;
                            }
                    }

                    if(!localIsValid)
                    {
                        poco.denyReasons.Add(comparer.Reason);
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    public void AddComparer(string propertyName, Operand op, object value, string reason)
    {
        _comparers.Add(new PropertyCompare() { PropertyName = propertyName, Operand = op, Value = value, Reason = reason });
    }
}
```

It wouldn't be difficult for you to be able to persist the property name, operand, and value details in a database or other such storage.  Assuming we fleshed out our enum above, we could conceivably do:

```
PropertyCompareRule rule = new PropertyCompareRule();
rule.AddComparer("typeID", Operand.Equal, 4, "Reason 1");
rule.AddComparer("benchMarkScore", Operand.LessThan, 10, "Reason 2");

bool valid = rule.IsValid(somePocoInstance);
```

**Edit: Some notes**

1. I use a `localIsValid` rather than bailing out at the first opportunity.  You can change this if you want, but the idea is that it allows a single rule to have multiple points of deniability.  This may or may not be what you wish - but it's easy enough to refactor the code so that it bails out the moment a single property comparison fails.
2. This is a nit-pick, but generally C# style-guidlines dictate properties shouldn't be camel-caps...  but that's entirely up to you at the end of the day :)

Comment: Interesting, I was thinking reflection would need to be involved somewhere. I'm going to take this and run with it and see where it gets me.

Comment: (Reflection is involved somewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, you are looking for some kind of a scripting system for business rules. I found this [blog post](http://et1337.wordpress.com/2011/12/10/c-for-scripting-runtime-compilation/) where some scripting environment are mentioned.

You can also create assemblies on the fly like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181855/1229622.