# Interpret command line arguments in C#

Tags: c#

I'd like to specify some command line arguments to a C# application. Meanwhile I want to interpret these arguments in C# "as-is".

For example, the argument may be in the form of:

```
" "\"" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToDate("yyyyMMdd") + "\"" "
```

so the correct behavior is to explain this argument as `"20140203"` (with quotes).

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: So, you want to execute C# code passed to your program as a commandline argument?

Comment: What you need is code compilation and execution at runtime. See [execute c# code at runtime from code file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181668/execute-c-sharp-code-at-runtime-from-code-file)

Comment: @Blorgbeard It's actually valid C# one-line statements rather than code. So I'm wondering if there's a better option rather than calling CodeDOM.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It's actually valid C# one-line statements rather than code. So I'm wondering if there's a better option rather than calling CodeDOM.

Comment: A one-line statement *is* code..

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Yes, sure, it's still code by definition...

Answer (score 0):

I'd would create a class library that was *in charge* of passing the data.

```
public class Parameters
{
  public string GetArgument()
  {
    // Create the string argument you want to pass.
  }

  public void SetProperties(string argument)
  {
    // parse data into this class's properties
  }

  public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can share the class between both applications, and make sure the the set/get are updated in the same way.