# Compiling C# code at runtime without creating a class

Tags: c#, codedom, runtime-compilation

Is it possble to compile a string into code without having to compile an entire new class?

Ive seen lots of tutorials and I have watched the documentations of the `CodeDom` framework, but in all of those it creates a new class and everything, what I want is to just compile 1 line and add it into the original code f.e.

```
string code = "5 + 1";
```

How can I compile that and at runtime use it like something like this:

```
double number = CompileAndCall("5 + 1");
```

`CompileAndCall()` should in some way convert the code to this:

```
return (double)5 + 1;
```

This should return the result (`(double)6`) from the method and store it in the `number` variable.

Comment: Like I said in the question, I want to alter code and while runtime.

Comment: As in original code I mean the code I compile and have in a text file in Visual Studios made by Microsoft. I dont know if CodeDom is the right approach, which is a one of the reasons why I made this question. Im pretty new to csharp and .Net and programming Microsoft stuff so I do not know many frameworks.

Comment: Exactly thats how I want it to work, like return.

Comment: Where does your `5 + 1` input come from? Can't you input `return 5 + 1;`? Does the output always have to be a double?

Comment: It is possible but it's too complicated for a beginner. Learn to use C# properly. learn about how .net works then try to to implement eval in c#. There are a number of ways of generating code on the fly and strings might not be the best fit for your purpose.

Comment: Microsoft Roslyn does exactly this. You can have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13321964/389966

Comment: @AdiLester The old CTPs did. The scripting API was removed from the newest preview while it's being redesigned.