# How to execute C# code at runtime in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a android application in Xamarin Studio.
I want to execute a code placed in the text (string).
For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181668/execute-c-sharp-code-at-runtime-from-code-file) question help me in Visual Studio Windows application. But I cannot use this answer in Xamarin Android.
This is my example in C# Windows application:

```
public class CodeLuncher
{
    public static void LunchCSCode(string site, string typeName, string methosName)
    {
        try
        {
            var provider = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("c#");
            var options = new CompilerParameters();
            string text = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(site);

            foreach (var item in GetRefrences(text))
            {
                options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(item);
            }
            string code = GetCode(text);
            var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { code });
            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var error in results.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var t = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType(typeName);
                t.GetMethod(methosName).Invoke(null, null);
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }


    static string[] GetRefrences(string text)
    {
        Regex regExp = new Regex("<Refrences>(.*?)</Refrences>", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        string str = regExp.Match(text).Groups[1].Value;
        List<string> retText = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in str.Trim().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            retText.Add(item);
        }
        return retText.ToArray();
    }

    static string GetCode(string text)
    {
        Regex regExp = new Regex("<CSharpCode>(.*?)</CSharpCode>", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        string str = regExp.Match(text).Groups[1].Value;
        return str.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your code look like? (which you want compile)

Comment: This is a pretty irregular requirement, you are usually able to work without such methods. Could you describe what you are trying achieve? Maybe there's an easier way for your case.

Comment: thanks friend for replay.
i want to check new version in my application from internet and download C# code from internet and show a message in my android application

Comment: or run a new activity from my C# downloaded code

Comment: Why do you need to compile c# in run time to check for new version of your app? Also running activity from dynamic c# code is pretty wild, could you explain further?

Comment: i want to show user new activity (with style and back-color) and version features. i want to show this activity in a runtime code.or that i want to add a plugin from internet in my android application.

Comment: That still doesn't explain WHY this needs to be done via dynamic code generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's complicated http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/limitations/

`Since applications on Android require generating Java proxy types during the build process, it is not possible to generate all code at runtime.`

From the `Limited Dynamic Language Support` and `Limited Java Generation Support` you can learn more about what specifically isn't supported. This means you might be able to work out certain code, but it won't work for any valid c# code.