# How to use a string variable as a command

Tags: c#

I want to use a string that I get from other methods as a command.I get setting name form the method call, and it is different everytime.

Example:

```
var SettingValue = string.Format("appPool.{0}", settingName);
```

Is it possible to use that string to do the following:

```
var what = appPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Time;
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you are going to need `Reflection`

Comment: This answer was most helpful IMHO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13321964/993547.

Comment: It's possible, though not simple, using reflection.  Especially if you want to be able to chain multiple functions.  It's even more complex if you want to retrieve the return value in a useful manner.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: thanx guys, seems like reflection is the way to go.