# How to read Code Lines from a Text in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change code manually by giving data from windows form. For that, I created a text file where i can change values/words. But, how to use those lines as C# code or how to read them from .txt file?

```
powerMill.Execute("ACTIVATE TOOLPATH TOOLPATH_2");
powerMill.Execute("EDIT TOOLAXIS ORIENTATION ON EDIT PAR 'PolarMilling.Active' '0'");
powerMill.Execute("EDIT PAR 'OrientationVector.Type' 'direction_of_travel'");
powerMill.Execute("EDIT PAR 'OrientationVector.OffsetAngle'  90");
```

Here i have to change "TOOLPATH_2" and "90" value in the code itself every time i run the program.

Can any help me.

Comment: These 4 lines are C# code in between main code. I want to read line by line and also consider these lines as code.

Comment: Base on my search `https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=read%20text%20file%20c%23`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can imagine.

**First one:**
Instead of trying to execute code `powerMill.Execute("...");` just read the strings itself and execute them:

Textfile:

```
ACTIVATE TOOLPATH TOOLPATH_2
EDIT TOOLAXIS ORIENTATION ON EDIT PAR
...
```

Code:

```
string[] input = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\pathToYourTextfile.txt");

foreach(string entry in input)
{
    powerMill.Execute(entry);
}
```

**The second way (if you really want to execute input):**

You could compile the input and execute it. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181668/execute-c-sharp-code-at-runtime-from-code-file) link. In case your input isnt much complicated I wouldnt recommend going this way. Depends on your goals in detail.