# c# - dynamically generate linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to dynamically generate a query to access certain columns from a datatable.

```
 string cols="row[Id],row[UserId], row[Code]";
 var result= (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
         select cols);
```

but this only returns "row[Id],row[UserId], row[Code]". How can I access the values in those columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically generate LINQ queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505189/dynamically-generate-linq-queries)

Comment: Why would this have to be "dynamic"?

Comment: @BiesiGrr  I get the list of columns to select only at run time..

Comment: @Madonna10 `DataRow` can get the value of the column by it's name. This should just work fine for what you're trying to do? Just use a simple loop

Comment: You can try running c# code at runtime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181668/execute-c-sharp-code-at-runtime-from-code-file  (Or much easier: If you are just want to select dynamic columns, just select them all `*` and from your code use whatever columns you want and ignore the rest)

Comment: Why not putting it in a dictionary? `Dictionary<string, object>` the key is the column name and the value is the value of the column?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this problem can be solved elegantly with a linq-based solution. It can be solved pretty easily using a loop and by accessing the column of the DataRow using the [Item property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public IEnumerable<object[]> GetValues(IList<string> columns, DataTable dt) {
  foreach (var row in dt.Rows) {
    var rowResult = new object[columns.Count];
    for (var col = 0; col < columns.Count; col++) {
      rowResult[col] = row.Item[columns[col]];
    }
    yield return rowResult;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not putting it in a dictionary? `Dictionary<string, object>` the key is the column name and the value is the value of the column.

```
        string[] cols = new string[] { "Id", "UserId", "Code" };
        var result = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
                      select cols.ToDictionary(c => c, c => row[c]));
```