# How to load functionality in a control in c# from a script?

Tags: javascript, c#, lua

First of all, the question should be a bit bigger but that is the main point, I guess.

Let me explain a little of what I want to do so you can have a better idea. Basically, id like to make a card game (no 3D nor 2D graphics), just a basic form where I have a deck of cards loaded in memory. After playing a card i'd like the form to update some information (labels, images, or X behavior) based on the card's effect, however, I don't want to hard code the card interactions/effects within the card control, I want to get all that from a script (for example a lua script). For example:

I have a script named "0001.lua" and it has 2 effects coded;

1. Deal 2 damage to opponent.
2. Deal 4 damage to opponent and destroy this card.

In the game I draw a card with ID 0001 and play it. When right clicking the control that works as a card, id like to display a list the effects in the script and depending on the chosen option to execute the selected function inside the script and update the information in the form (if it was effect 2 - deal 4 damage and destroying the control/card).

with all this in mind id like to ask the following questions:

How can i achieve something like that?
Is that called "embedding"? 
In the information I mentioned lua as the scripting language but I don't know if that is the simplest scripting language i can use to do this, is there a simpler scripting language? I would like to keep it as simple as possible.

Can anyone provide an example to do something like this? I'll greatly appreciate it (it's okay if it's simple, I just want to know how to accomplish the back and forth communication between the script and c#)

Also, c# is no a requisite. I just mentioned c# because I feel comfortable coding in it. If there is another language more appropriate for this task i'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is much more simple to use C# scripts from C# than lua.

Check out these questions 
[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181668/execute-c-sharp-code-at-runtime-from-code-file),
[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments).

*Note: Don't forget about namespaces. If you want your scripts classes  to inherit your classes or interfaces from main application, then your scripts should use same namespace.*

Comment: Aright! i'm looking into it, make some tests and come back at a later time. Thanks! :D