# Implement and store card effects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a card game right now and I have learned some strategy from [execute c# code at runtime from code file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181668/execute-c-sharp-code-at-runtime-from-code-file) and [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments) about how to implement the card effects.

Since I am using unity, and I know that there is a kind of script called `ScriptableObject`, which will take less space than normal script. Can I store the card effect implementation through `ScriptableObject` as well? I am already using it to store some basic card attributes like name and description. But I don't think it is good to use it to store card effect implementation. Is there a space-saving way to store it? Or I have to create a normal script?

[image][image]

And any advice on how to implement the card effects will be appreciated since I only have a rough sense of how to do that.

Comment: are you talking about data saving or rendering of the effect?

Comment: @David The former. For instance, how to implement the card effect in the description part in the photo. Right now  I am thinking I should write a trigger class and then each card effects will inherit from that. So my problem is to find a good way to put the card effect implementation functions. Should I just use the normal script or there is a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: What exactly is a *card effect implementation*? If it's just code then space will not be an issue here.

Comment: @Lece Please look at the description of fat soldier card. My question is like how I implement that? How do I store that implementation?

Comment: @Lece It will be a script of class, like you said just code, as far as I am concerned. Because I know scriptobject seems better,  I am wondering whether there is a better way to store code.

Comment: You can either write vanilla C# classes, initialise and call into them as required, write components (Monobehaviours) and attach them to your GameObject or create ScriptableObject assets and drag them into the Inspector. In this context there's little difference between the three other than how you create and use them.

Answer (score 0):

To save info:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HeartCounts", 3);
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Description", "Some words");
```

To restore:

```
int n = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HeartCounts", 0);
var desc= PlayerPrefs.GetString("Description", "Some words");
```

Comment: I mean not this kind of info. What I want to save is some functions not data.